# Programmatically update Xcode Targets Build Settings

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-extensions

I've an Xcode iOS project with two targets. Each of these targets includes a third target which is an iOS Extension (Widget). Is there a way to update the Widget build settings based on the choosen build target?

I've already setup some pre-actions in the Xcode target build scheme to update the `Info.plist` file of the Widget with the parent bundle identifier:

```
# BundleIdentifier
bundleIdentifier=${PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER}
# Widget Identifier
widgetIdentifier="WidgetName"
# updating BundleIdentifier in widget InfoPlist
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Set :CFBundleIdentifier $bundleIdentifier.$widgetIdentifier" "${SRCROOT}/${widgetIdentifier}/ConfigFiles/Info.plist"
```

My two main targets bundle identifiers are `com.company.firstname` and `com.company.secondname`. As you can see, I was able to update the `Info.plist` of the Widget, specifically the `CFBundleIdentifier` key.
Can i do something similar to this to update the build settings parameter of the Widget `Product Bundle Identifier`? I need to update the Widget build settings to be something like `com.company.firstname.widgetname` or `com.company.secondname.widgetname` based on the current target.

Comment: @matt can you provide some code to set an environment variable via script as you said?

Comment: Check out using a different build scheme for each build. That will allow you to define your bundle identifier as a build setting without having to use scripts.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to edit project.pbxproj particularly the Build Settings values for Other Linker Flags (Debug)